# In iTerm2, can you set multiple working directories in tabs for a Profile on startup?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I'm doing a lot of work with [Roots](https://roots.io), a dev-friendly WordPress setup. I'd like to open up multiple tabs in [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) (vagrant box, WP app directory, theme directory etc) but I can only find how to set one working directory in `Preferences > Profiles > General > 'Working Directory'`.

Is there a simple way of setting initial working directories in multiple tabs when opening a Profile?